# How can I download a PDF file with WGET authentication and set the PDFextension on the dowloaded file?

Tags: pdf, download, wget

I want to download a pdf file with wget

The URL is like this:

```
example.com/pdfdl/?pdfnumberid=245
```

This URL doesn’t have `.pdf` extension at the end of the parameter and for downloading it need just login to site.

I used this command:

```
wget --user=myuser --password=mypass example.com/pdfdl/?pdfnumberid=245
```

When I run this code, it downloads a file without extension and its unreadable

How should I do it?

**EDIT**: When I use Bash it gives me “HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found.” It makes no difference if you put `.pdf` at the end of the file or not. Every corrupted `.pdf` file which downloaded from Bash are in the same size. I think there is problem with login because it show redirection in Bash 302 error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name of the output file with the `-O` option

```
wget --user=myuser --password=mypass -O pdf-245.pdf example.com/pdfdl/?pdfnumberid=245
```

Comment: It needs to be uppercase `O` like this: `-O`. The lowercase `-o` option is for logging output messages to a log file. The uppercase `-O` is for indicating an output file.

Comment: Hello . I said it download the pdf file but it is corrupted . adobe reader says : Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open '245.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Comment: @amir So what do you see if you open the file in a text editor? Or perhaps just run `cat 245.pdf` from the command line (assuming you are in macOS or Linux for `cat` but in general check the file’s contents).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 when I download directly without Wget , file open correctly . I said that at the end of the url we cant see ".pdf" extension . i think problem is about this

Comment: You now have a `.pdf` suffix - most likely there is something else wrong. Please run `head pdf-245.pdf` and let us know the output

Comment: @amir Regardless of whether the file is dowloaded explicitly with a `.pdf` extension or not, if you simply add a `.pdf` extension and the file is a valid PDF the file will load. If the file is *not* loading even if you add a `.pdf` extension then something else is wrong in the data being retrieved. Perhaps there is security that prevents command line downloads? If so if you look at the contents of the unopenable file it is mostly likely a 404 or 401 error in plain text and not a PDF file. At the end of this you *must* check the contents of that downloaded file to gain insight into it.

Comment: dear @Giacomo1968 when I login to website from firefox and click on download link , it works correctly and it downloads pdf file . but when I use bash it gives me "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found" . there is no different that you put .pdf at the end or not. every corrupted pdf file which downloaded from bash are in the same size . i thing there is problem with login because it show redirection in bash 302 error.

Comment: As long as you don't tell us, what is in the file (it ist not really a PDF but most likely an error message), we can't help you.

Comment: @amir 302 is not an error. It is “302 found” and is a temporary redirect. If that is the issue, use Curl instead. Will update my answer to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

Change your command to use the `-O` option to indicate the name of the output file like this:

```
wget --user=myuser --password=mypass -O 245.pdf example.com/pdfdl/?pdfnumberid=245
```

Your file will then be downloaded as `245.pdf`.

---

But if you are getting a 302 status from the request that means it is a “[302 Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302)” redirect.

> “The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 302 Found redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header.”

In a case like that I would recommend using [Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) instead like this:

```
curl -Lk -u username:password example.com/pdfdl/?pdfnumberid=245 -o 245.pdf
```

- The `-L` tells the command to follow locations; meaning 302 and 301 redirects.
- The `-k` forces insecure SSL connections which is something that might be needed when accessing HTTPS sites from the command line; feel free to remove that if you wish to see what happens.
- The `-u username:password` is the username and password.
- The URL for the source file follows.
- Finally the `-o` is the output file.

Comment: Hello . I said it download the pdf file but it is corrupted . adobe reader says : Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open '245.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Comment: @amir This answer is now updated to show you how to use Curl to download a file with authentication and redirects in place.

Comment: Dear @Giacomo1968 thank you a lot but I used this code but the downloaded file was corrupted again . (it didn't show me any error while running code) .It is noteworthy, I test a wrong username password but it download that corrupted file again with exact size . so after running code just build a corrupted pdf file ! it doesn't matter even what you write for username and password

Comment: @amir When you say: “I test a wrong username password but it download that corrupted file again with exact size.” Then it means there is something else happening with the website you are attempting to download the PDF from where they might be blocking your access attempts or they are using a different authentication scheme than simply a username and password. Whatever it is, unless we know the exact site you are dealing with, sorry to say nobody here can really help you.